# How to install npm live-server?

Tags: npm

I am getting the following errors on trying to install npm live-server.
Can someone help.

```
C:\Users\kacho\Desktop\Web Development\Background Gradient\background-generator>npm install -g live-server
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/live-server failed, reason: write EPROTO 10472:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kacho\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-29T15_34_35_575Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears to be `SSL` related:

> write EPROTO 10472:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:
>   npm ERR!

Perhaps you could try setting your registry as follows and reinstalling the `live-server` library like so:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm i live-server
```

As this action ensures you're connecting to npmjs with `ssl`.

If this doesn't work, you could try removing the `ssl` requirement and connecting to npmjs as follows:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm i live-server
```

Lastly, if neither of the above mentioned actions work (*use at your own discretion*) you could disable the `ssl` requirement altogether by doing the following:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm i live-server
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hi Nathan,

Thank you for your help. But I am still getting error. Can you please tell me how can I remove #ssl requirement.

Comment: @sohrabkacho did you try setting those npm env variables and reinstalling as suggested? Also, are you on a corporate network?

Comment: yes, I did try those. Although both of them were the same commands.
Also I am no my institute's network behind a proxy, and I have already set the proxy for npm.

Comment: @sohrabkacho the first suggestion is using ssl to connect to npmjs whereas the second isn't, notice `http` to `https` for the protocol. The third suggestion is saying don't use ssl with the caveat of deliberately saying I accept the risk of not connecting securely. Not sure if you're on your company's network but if so I would verify your proxy configuration is correct by using `npm config ls` to check your npm config settings. If your proxy isn't set or is set incorrectly change it with the following cmd: `npm config set proxy <proxy_config>`. Cheers!

Comment: Solved the problem. Had to set the proxy for both http and https. Thank you for all the help Nathan.

Comment: np @sohrabkacho please consider accepting my answer if you found it helpful